# how to apply $setunion for this aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

```
Here my db is:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d28667fb0adb622b905ccd2"),
    "requestedDate" : ISODate("2019-07-12T10:52:47.711Z"),
    "requestType" : "A",
    "isRequestSuccess" : false,
    "responseDate" : ISODate("2019-07-12T10:53:19.213Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d28667fb0adb622b905ccd2"),
    "requestedDate" : ISODate("2019-07-12T10:52:47.711Z"),
    "requestType" : "C",
    "isRequestSuccess" : false,
    "responseDate" : ISODate("2019-07-12T10:53:19.213Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d28667fb0adb622b905ccd2"),
    "requestedDate" : ISODate("2019-07-12T10:52:47.711Z"),
    "requestedType" : "A",
    "isRequestSuccess" : false,
    "responseDate" : ISODate("2019-07-12T10:53:19.213Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need to get the values by each requestType and also isRequestSuccess: sucess or failure wise.

```
[
  { requestedType: "A", isRequestSuccess: 2, isRequestFalse: 1 },
  { requestedType: "C", isRequestSuccess: 1, isRequestFalse: 3 }
]
```

How can I get those values?

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: [ { requestedType: 'A', isRequestSuccess: 2,isRequestFalse:1 },
  { requestedType: 'C', isRequestSuccess: 1,isRequestFalse:3 } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate({
  "$group": {
      "_id": "$requestedType",
      "isRequestSuccess": {
          $sum: {
              $cond: ["$isRequestSuccess", 1, 0]
          }
      },
      "isRequestFalse": {
          $sum: {
              $cond: ["$isRequestSuccess", 0, 1]
          }
      }
  }
 })
```